# Are these two definitions stably isomorphic modules / $K_0(A)$ equivalent?

Tags: projective-module, algebraic-k-theory

Let $A$ be a ring with $1$. I have encountered two definitions of stably isomorphic (left) $A$-modules.

**Def. 1.** Two finitely generated $A$-modules $M,N$ are stably isomorphic if there exists $r,s\geq 0$ such that $M\times A^r\simeq N\times A^s.$

**Def. 2.** Two finitely generated $A$-modules $M,N$ are stably isomorphic if there exists $n\geq 0$ such that $M\times A^n\simeq N\times A^n.$

**Question 1.** Are these two definitions equivalent ?

Theis question is motivated by the following. Let $Proj(A)$ be the commutative monoid of isomorphism classes $<M>$ of finitely generated projective modules, the internal law being given by: $<M>+<N>=<M\times N>$.

Once again, I know two possible definitions of the group $K_0(A)$.

**Def 1'.** $K_0(A)$ is the quotient of the free abelian group on $Proj(A)$ by the relations $ <M_2>=<M_1>+<M_3>$ whenever we have a short exact sequence $0\to M_1\to M_2\to M_3\to 0$.
If we denote by $[M]$ the image of $<M>$ under the canonical projection, we have

$[M]=[N]$ if and only if $M$ and $N$ are stably isomorphic in the sense of Def 1.

**Def  2'.** $K_0(A)$ is the Grothendieck group (i.e. symmetrization) of the monoid $Proj(A)$, that is the quotient set of $Proj(A)\times Proj(A)$ wrt to the equivalence relation $$(<M_1>,<N_1>)\sim (<M_2>,<N_2>)\iff \exists \ <P>\in Proj(A), <M_1>+ <N_2>+<P>=<M_2>+<N_1>+<P>.$$

If $[M]$ denotes this time the class of $(<M>,0)$, we have $[M]=[N]$ if and only if $M$ and $N$ are stably isomorphic in the sense of Def. 2.

**Question 2.** Do these two constructions yield isomorphic groups ?

Of course, if Def 1 and Def 2 are equivalent, this is clear, but if not, it is not so clear to me.

I do not know any counterexample though, at least amongst all the very few examples of $K_0$ I am aware of.

**EDIT.** The answer of Question 2 is obviously NO (see the answer of A. Pongracz). So I guess the real interesting question is Question 2.

Thanks in advance of any enlightning thoughts.

Greg

Answer (score 1):

Unless there are hidden conditions, the answer to question $1$ is no. 
It is already false for $A=\mathbb{Z}$. 
For finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-modules (i.e., finitely generated Abelian groups) the notion of rank makes sense. 
So $\mathbb{Z}^a\not \cong \mathbb{Z}^b$ for $a\neq b\in \mathbb{N}$. 
So two such modules satisfy definition $1$ but not definition $2$.

In fact, the same argument works for any PID due to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_theorem_for_finitely_generated_modules_over_a_principal_ideal_domain

Comment: Indeed...I should have thought about this. In fact, your argument works for any ring $A$ (commutative or not) for which, for all $m,n\geq 0, A^m\simeq A^n\Rightarrow m=n$. This includes any commutative ring, or division rings.